# Drive an HX-53 IR Transmitter using an ESP32 and logic level converter

Tags: esp32, logic-level, 5v, 3.3v

I have an ESP32 with which I need to drive an HX-53 IR transmitter.

I'm facing some range problems particularly for three reasons:

1. The HX-53 is supposed to be driven with 5 V.
2. There is an LED in series with the IR LED.
3. ESP32 output pin current is quite low.

For this reason I would like to understand whether i can use something like this (although overkill, but cheap compare to a single channel for example):

[image: BSS138 based logic converter]

To convert my GPIO output to a 5 V signal and with higher current available to the IR LED.

The carrier frequency is 38 kHz and I was wondering whether I would incur in lag/delay due to  this circuit.

[image]

The shop is saying (not sure how trustable):
Infrared emission distance: about 1.3 meters (5 V 38 kHz)
Infrared emission angle: about 20 degrees.

And I would like to reach 3 m roughly.

Diagram:

[image]

Comment: Please provide a link to the data sheet for the HX-53

Comment: there is no datasheet unfortunately, the HX-53 is your typical chinese low cost breakout board. The circuit is quite easy to figure out.

Comment: Please figure it out and post it.

Comment: Unless DAT signal is negative, your LEDs are backwards.

Comment: got it, since that is secondary to the question ill fix it soon